# Subclass of AsyncTask in Kotlin - unable to use primary constructor parameter within onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a subclass of `AsyncTask` implemented in Kotlin:

```
class SignUpTask(responseHandler: SignUpTaskResponseHandler): AsyncTask<Agent, Void, Boolean>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Agent?): Boolean {
        // Some awesome code
        return true
    }
    override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
        result?.let {
            if (it) {
                responseHandler.agentCreationSucceeded()
            } else {
                // agent creation failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is - I am getting below error at this line `responseHandler.agentCreationSucceeded()`:

> Unresolved reference: responseHandler

I can make it work by explicitly declaring a property and assigning it the parameter passed in constructor:

```
class SignUpTask(responseHandler: SignUpTaskResponseHandler): AsyncTask<Agent, Void, Boolean>() {
        val internalResponseHandler = responseHandler // explicit assignment to make it work inside onPostExecute
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Agent?): Boolean {
            // Some awesome code
            return true
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
            result?.let {
                if (it) {
                    // Works only after explicit assignment?
                    internalResponseHandler.agentCreationSucceeded()
                } else {
                    // agent creation failed
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on why this overhead or am I missing anything over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
class SignUpTask(val responseHandler: SignUpTaskResponseHandler): AsyncTask<Agent, Void, Boolean>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Agent?): Boolean {
            // Some awesome code
            return true
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
            result?.let {
                if (it) {
                    // Works only after explicit assignment?
                    responseHandler.agentCreationSucceeded()
                } else {
                    // agent creation failed
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason is variable scope. `responseHandler : SignUpTaskResponseHandler` is defined only in the class constructor. if you specify it as a val variable, it will defined as a class property.

Comment: there's no val named internalResponseHandler in your code

Comment: For future readers, can you clarify your answer to describe the changes.  Otherwise you are forcing people to diff the code.  You changed `responseHandler` to add `val` keyword in front, and removed the additional `internalResponseHandler` variable.  Then you can use `responseHandler` directly.